# import python module

Tags: python

I tried to install a module using easy install. It seems to have been installed but I am not able to import it.

```
# easy_install uuid
Searching for uuid
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/uuid/
Reading http://zesty.ca/python/
Best match: uuid 1.30
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/u/uuid/uuid-1.30.tar.gz#md5=639b310f1fe6800e4bf8aa1dd9333117
Processing uuid-1.30.tar.gz
Running uuid-1.30/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-mQlxdg/uuid-1.30/egg-dist-tmp-gLpk9N
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding uuid 1.30 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/uuid-1.30-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for uuid
Finished processing dependencies for uuid


# python
>>> import uuid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: No module named uuid


# python -V
Python 2.4.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `easy_install` clearly indicates that the module was installed to `/usr/lib/python2.6`, but you're running Python 2.4.

Either run Python 2.6 explicitly (e.g. `python2.6` or `python26`), or use `python -m easy_install uuid` to install the module to your default Python.

Comment: The [documentation](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#multiple-python-versions) also indicates that you can specify the version that `easy_install` targets on the command line. (e.g. `easy_install-2.4`)

Comment: Yup. But, on occasion, I've run into situations where multiple copies of the same version of Python are installed (on OS X, this can happen if you install 'python.org' Python alongside the system Python). In that case, it's best to disambiguate using the interpreter invocation itself.

Comment: That's not likely to help, since if you have two `python-2.6`s you're anyways going to get the one that is first on `PATH` just as you would if you ran `easy_install-2.6`.

Comment: Right, which would also be the `python` you intended to run in the first place (OP was starting the first `python` on `PATH`).

Comment: @nneonneo: Hm yes, I didn't consider that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at what you posted :)?

```
Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/uuid-1.30-py2.6.egg

# python -V
Python 2.4.3
```

If you're using Python 2.6 (which you should, since even that is old by now, 2.4 is ancient), the `uuid` module should be present already, so you shouldn't need to install it anyhow.

Comment: I think you meant _which you `shouldn't`_

Comment: No I meant should, as opposed to the 2.4 he has. Although if 2.7 is an option sure that's good too.